# Python input does not compare properly

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I did this on test today and came back to test it. I know better ways to do this but why is this not working?

```
def f():
    e=raw_input('enter number')
    if e in range (12):
        print 'co'
    if e in range (12,20):
        print 'co2'
    if e in range (-10,0,1):
        print 'co3'

f()
```

Comment: Define "not working" and please describe what you've done to make it "work".

Comment: the code as is didn't work i wanted it to print those statements i thought it was self explanatory

Comment: I don't think i understand your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e is a string and you compare it to an int

do

```
def f():
    e=int(raw_input('enter number'))
    if e in range (12):
        print 'co'
    elif e in range (12,20):
        print 'co2'
    elif e in range (-10,0,1):
        print 'co3'

f()
```

instead

Comment: Use `elif` statements please.

Comment: did it. I just didnt do it at first because i wanted to show him the position where the problem is.

Comment: It's ok, but then you should also include a better code illustrating why it is better.

Comment: thanks one day I will create apps lol

Answer (score 0):

`e=raw_input('enter number')` should be `e=int(raw_input('enter number'))` Unlike `input()`, `raw_input()` simply returns the input as a string, irrespective of what the input is. Since `range(12)` consists of the integers 0-11 inclusive but `e` is not an integer, `e` will never be in `range(12)`. Thus `e` needs to be converted into an integer. Fortunately, there is a built-in function for that: `int()`.

Comment: thanks doubt shell take off points for that lol